# Count values on dataset attribute with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, conditional-statements

I need your help. I have dataset from my csv file looks like this.

```
Date                       Service
2020/10/27 00:00:00+00     1
2020/10/27 00:00:00+00     1
2020/10/28 00:00:00+00     3
2020/10/28 00:00:00+00     4
2020/10/28 00:00:00+00     5
2020/10/29 00:00:00+00     5
2020/10/29 00:00:00+00     6
```

I want to make output like this.

```
Date                       Service
2020/10/27                 2
2020/10/28                 12
2020/10/29                 11
```

np: I have a large dataset about 5 months of data

And yes please, also help me to delete the clock because later I want to make time-series plot with matplotlib.pyplot. Thanks for help.

Comment: `df.groupby('Date').sum()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `resample` or `groupby` to achieve your aggregation. Then you can use the datetime `Series` accessor to format your dates how you want (Year/Month/Day):

```
# ensure "Date" is a datetime dtype if it isn't
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]) 

# Resample getting the sum of every day in the "Date" column
aggregated_df = df.resample("D", on="Date").sum().reset_index()
aggregated_df["Date"] = aggregated_df["Date"].dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

print(aggregated_df)
         Date  Service
0  2020/10/27        2
1  2020/10/28       12
2  2020/10/29       11
```